# Getting outside of an overflow:hidden box in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, overflow, css-position

I'm trying to create a popup box that will appear in the middle of the page.  The outer box  is defined by the CMS we're using and it has an overflow:hidden and width:250px style attached.  The inner box that we want to "get out of the outer box" is under our control and we can do pretty much anything we want.

Unfortunately everything we try in IE won't let the popup "escape" from the grip of the parent box's overflow:hidden.  Moving the popup outside of the parent div, in our case, is not possible.

Note - all other browsers we've tested works as we would like.

Here's a simple example.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="width:250px; overflow:hidden; background-color:#dddddd;">
        <p>
            Here is some text that appears within the primary outer box.
        </p>
        <div id='popup2' style="position:absolute; z-index:500; top:0px; left:0px; width:400px; height:200px; background-color:pink;">
            <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('popup2').style.display = 'none'; return false;">Close</a><br/>
            This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup.
            This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup.
            This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup. This is the popoup.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of IE and do you have a doctype/is it in compatability mode?

Comment: Have you tried using fixed instead of absolute?

Comment: IE-8 and IE-9 both appear the same, I do not have a doctype in the file (if you suggest one, I'll put it in).  The code posted is a simple case of that I'm trying to do.

Comment: Fixed layout doesn't position the box, it just puts it below (like inline)

Answer (score 1):

I'm only able to test it in IE9 at the moment, but if you include a strict doctype it works correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/wgWZv/

jsfiddle uses html 5

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

I tested it with 4 strict and it works as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: THANK YOU.  I added the <!DOCTYPE HTML> and it works in both IE8 and IE9.  I don't have IE-7 or IE-6 available for testing, but would be interested if anyone does have those, could test it out.